# Getting trouble with picking most and less valued day from an array

Tags: java, arrays

I have this piece of code, array of 7 days, the user enter which day and how many tickets per day.
the loop will continue untill the number is greater than 50(of total tickets).
I want to pick the most wanted day, and the less one.
This is the code:

```
int ticketCounter=0;
final int MAX_TICKET=50;
int[] dayOfTicket=new int[7];
int mostWantedDay=dayOfTicket[0];
int LessWantedDay=dayOfTicket[0];
int indexOfWantedDay=0;
int indexOfLessWantedDay=0;
 while(ticketCounter<=MAX_TICKET){
    System.out.println("Enter the day number (1-7) and the number of tickets:");
    int whichDay=s.nextInt();
    int numberOfTicket=s.nextInt();

        if(whichDay>0 && whichDay<8){
        dayOfTicket[whichDay-1]+=numberOfTicket;
        ticketCounter+=numberOfTicket;
        }else{
        System.out.println("Invalid input.\n");
        }   
    }
}
    for(int f=0;f<dayOfTicket.length;f++){
        if(dayOfTicket[f]>mostWantedDay){
            indexOfWantedDay=f+1;
        }
        if(dayOfTicket[f]<LessWantedDay){
            indexOfLessWantedDay=f+1;
        }
System.out.printf("The day with max tickets is: %d \nThe day with min tickets is: %d \n\n",indexOfWantedDay, indexOfLessWantedDay);
```

it is picking wrong most wanted day, and always print 0 as less wanted day.
I have some problems with this checking method on the last for loop.
I will aprriciate your help.
thanks

EDIT: I took out the for loop outside the WHILE ( it was my copy paste mistake)

Comment: How about finding the `mostWantedDay` and the `LessWantedDay` *after* you have all the necessary data from the user?

Comment: That was a copy paste mistake, the for loop is outside the while

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of the problem is when you initialize `LessWantedDay`, you initially set it to 0.

Initialize this value to the maximum possible by using

```
int LessWantedDay=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

Furthermore, you need to update the logic within your check to filter out 0's (assuming you want to print a day that doesn't have 0 tickets), and to update your max/min values as you parse the `dayOfTicket` array.

```
for(int f=0;f<dayOfTicket.length;f++){
    if(dayOfTicket[f]>mostWantedDay){
        indexOfWantedDay=f+1;
        mostWantedDay = dayOfTicket[f];
    }
    if(dayOfTicket[f]<LessWantedDay && dayOfTicket[f] > 0){
        indexOfLessWantedDay=f+1;
        LessWantedDay = dayOfTicket[f]
    }
}
```

Tested output:

```
Enter the day number (1-7) and the number of tickets:
1 10
Enter the day number (1-7) and the number of tickets:
3 5
Enter the day number (1-7) and the number of tickets:
5 20
Enter the day number (1-7) and the number of tickets:
4 15
Enter the day number (1-7) and the number of tickets:
6 10
The day with max tickets is: 5 
The day with min tickets is: 3
```

Comment: I have no idea why I didnt keep this thing on, I made few changes and I totally forgot to brought it back, ( the new sets of the variables) , thanks again for all your help guys, it makes sense :)

Comment: Glad I could help! It's always the little details that break your program, which are also the hardest to find.

Comment: acutally, the less wanted day, still print 0.

Comment: What is your use case? I have tested with success... For what inputs does the min tickets produce 0?

Comment: I dont know, I tried several examples, all of them gave me zero for the lowest

Comment: Make sure you have updated your code to add int LessWantedDay=Integer.MAX_VALUE; I have tried several examples and cannot get the program to print 0. Please give me a specific example that I can try on my end. For example "5 2, 6 20, 7 20, 1 10"

Comment: Oh I didnt do it, As I said in another comment, I cannot use this method for now, I need another solution with basic methods.

Comment: I still don't understand how my answer isn't correct? I cannot produce an invalid output (less wanted day of 0).

Answer (score 2):

The reason your less wanted day is always printing 0 is because that's most likely lower than the input being entered in.

An alternative would be to set the lessWantedDay value to INTEGER.MAX_VALUE, or just the max ticket value, or another arbitrary random large number, like 9001, 100000, something like that.

An alternative alternative (in case you can't use a basic thing mentioned above) is that you can set the LessWantedDay and mostWantedDay to be the first element of the array after you get the input from the user.

```
    int mostWantedDay;
    int LessWantedDay;
    <snipped out input logic/>
    mostWantedDay = dayOfTicket[0];
    LessWantedDay = dayOfTicket[0];
```

Whenever you find a most and least day, you need to update the values of mostWantedDay and LessWantedDay with the values you found

so your if statements would look like this:

```
 if(dayOfTicket[f]>mostWantedDay){
        indexOfWantedDay=f+1;
        mostWantedDay = dayOfTicket[f];
    }
    if(dayOfTicket[f]<LessWantedDay){
        indexOfLessWantedDay=f+1;
        LessWantedDay = dayOfTicket[f];
    }
```

Comment: @rassko int LessWantedDay=Integer.MAX_VALUE;, have you tried using that like myself and someone else mentioned using, then running it?

Comment: I can't use this method for now, I need it with simple methods.

Comment: @rassko is the code in the question the current version?

Comment: Yep, this the current one... without your suggesstions, which for me only the max day works, the less wanted day still print zero for some reason

Comment: Set LessWantedDay to some random large number, something like 20000, or something along those lines.

Comment: Thats works, But this is like outsolution the MAX INTEGER. There is any way to set this minimum value without this trick ? thanks!

Comment: Why can't you use max integer?

Answer (score 2):

This code is almost completely correct.

In your loops, where you say:

```
for(int f=0;f<dayOfTicket.length;f++){
    if(dayOfTicket[f]>mostWantedDay){
        indexOfWantedDay=f+1;
    }
    if(dayOfTicket[f]<LessWantedDay){
        indexOfLessWantedDay=f+1;
    }
}
```

You should not set the index to "f+1", that would be the index after where we are in the loop, and we want where we actually are.

Also, this will overwrite the highest day with the last day that is more than the variable "mostWantedDay" and vise versa for "lessWantedDay. What you need to do is after you find a number of tickets that is higher than your current high, or lower than your current low, set it to that.

This way, when testing, you test against the highest or lowest one yet. As of right now, you are continuously testing against the first index's number because that is stored in most/lessWantedDay and is never changed.

After changes, your code will look like:

```
for(int f=0;f<dayOfTicket.length;f++){
    if(dayOfTicket[f]>mostWantedDay){
        indexOfWantedDay=f;
        mostWantedDay = dayOfTicket[f];
    }
    if(dayOfTicket[f]<LessWantedDay){
        indexOfLessWantedDay=f;
        LessWantedDay[f] = dayOfTicket[f];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats not true, since my array list is from 0 to 6, and my first day is 1. So I will always need to +1 to the index to make it the real day.

Comment: Yes it is true. Since you are calling that variable "INDEXOfWantedDay" It is apparently referring to the INDEX. The index of day 1 is 0, the index of day 2 is 1. If you want it to refer to the day, maybe you should name it appropiately "mostWantedDay".